# Inputting quantiles to ggplot geom_boxplot using rpy2 in python

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, pandas, rpy2

I have the following boxplot:

```
import os
iris = pandas.read_table(os.path.expanduser("~/iris.csv"),
                         sep=",")
iris["Species"] = iris["Name"]
r_melted = conversion_pydataframe(iris)
p = ggplot2.ggplot(r_melted) + \
    ggplot2.geom_boxplot(aes_string(**{"x": "PetalLength",
                                       "y": "PetalWidth",
                                       "fill": "Species"})) + \
    ggplot2.facet_grid(Formula("Species ~ .")) + \
    ggplot2.coord_flip()
p.plot()
```

My question is: how can I change the whiskers/quantiles being plotted in the boxplot? Assume I have a dataframe where I can compute the quantiles by rows or columns, as in:

```
quantiles_df = iris.quantiles(q=0.85, axis=1)
```

Then how can I use `quantiles_df` as input to `geom_boxplot` so that it plots for example the 0.2 to 0.85 percentiles rather than the standard 0.25 to 0.75? thank you.

Comment: can you post your full code? you're importing `pandas`. anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from this in R. First calculate the percentiles per Species for a variable (here Petal.Width) and use these for the plot. By specifying `ymin` (=lower whisker boundary), `lower` (=lower boundary of box), `middle` (= line in box ), `upper` (= upper boundary of box),`ymax`(= upper whisker boundary) and adding `stat = "identity"` you can customize the boxplots.

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

dataf <- ddply(iris, .(Species), summarize, quantilesy= quantile(Petal.Width, c(0,0.2, 0.5,0.85,1 )))
dataf$Labels <- rep(c("0%", "20%","50%","85%", "100%"),length(unique(dataf$Species)))

dataf2 <- reshape(dataf , idvar = c("Species"),timevar = "Labels", direction = "wide")
datafmeanx <- ddply(iris, .(Species), summarize, meanx= mean(Petal.Length))
dataf3 <- merge(dataf2,datafmeanx)

b <- ggplot(dataf3 , aes(x=meanx,ymin = `quantilesy.0%`, lower = `quantilesy.20%`, middle = `quantilesy.50%`, upper = `quantilesy.85%`, ymax = `quantilesy.100%`))
b + geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")+ facet_grid(Species~.) + xlab("Mean PetalLength") + ylab("PetalWidth")
```

**EDIT: If you don't want to use the backticks (see comment):**

```
dataf$Labels <- rep(c("0", "20","50","85", "100"),length(unique(dataf$Species)))

dataf2 <- reshape(dataf , idvar = c("Species"),timevar = "Labels", direction = "wide")
datafmeanx <- ddply(iris, .(Species), summarize, meanx= mean(Petal.Length))
dataf3 <- merge(dataf2,datafmeanx)

b <- ggplot(dataf3 , aes(x=meanx ,ymin = quantilesy.0, lower = quantilesy.20, middle = quantilesy.50, upper = quantilesy.85, ymax = quantilesy.100))
b + geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")+ facet_grid(Species~.) + xlab("Mean PetalLength") + ylab("PetalWidth")
```

[image]

Comment: can you explain the final format of dataf3? and what are those backquotes doing? it'll be difficult to translate those `ddply` calls to pandas. I guess `groupby` should be used but I find this format very cryptic so it's hard to translate to python

Comment: Because "%" is an illegal characters in ggplot I had to enclose the names in backticks. If you drop the "%" sign, you can make the plot without ticks. I added it. Try to run it in R to see the final format of dataf3. The rows are the species, the calculated quantiles and meanx are the columns, so a dataframe with 3 rows and 7 columns.